# Is there a way to call another pipeline from stage?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I got 2 pipelines: A and B.
In pipeline A I got 2 stages: A1, A2.
I would like pipeline B to be called after stage A1 finished and stage A2 needs to wait for external pipeline to complete (in a synchronous manner).

On the timeline it would like like this:

1. Pipeline A starts
2. Stage A1 starts and finishes
3. External pipeline is invoked
4. Stage A2 starts when external pipeline finished successfully

Tried putting resources section like this in pipeline A, but it didn't work:

resources:

```
  pipelines:
      - pipeline: pipeline-B
        source: pipeline-B
        trigger:
          stages: 
            - StageA1
```

Comment: You will need to create a new stage on step 3 and trigger your build pipeline. When this stage finishes successfully you should get the result and if OK you can continue with your execution. A tutorial on how to trigger an azure devops build pipeline using the rest api can be found on  https://blog.geralexgr.com/cloud/trigger-azure-devops-build-pipelines-using-rest-api

Comment: The last time I did this, I deadlocked my build system. My pipeline A started pipeline B using the REST API, and waited for B to finish. However, I only have 1 agent in my agent pools so A is waiting for B to finish to continue while B is waiting for A to complete so it can start. Make sure you have more than 1 agent in your pool!

Comment: @CodeDifferent
We have 12 Microsoft hosted agents.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, seems there's no way so far to do what you want in single pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

Perhaps what you can do is to create several pipelines instead of stages, and create a chain for execution, one after the other, in the order you need.